# TypeError update() got multiple values for argument 'upsert' with $setOnInsert

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to scan through the file system for files - if the file is in the DB then update. If not then insert a new record. but I am getting this error "TypeError update() got multiple values for argument 'upsert'"

What am I doing wrong here?

```
def scan_for_file(dir_path, storage_bucket):
    for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
        curpath = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
        if os.path.isfile(curpath):
            print('found file:', file)
            print('checking db')
            collection = db.file_collection
            cursor = collection.find({'file_path': curpath})
            for document in cursor:
                file_db_id = document['_id']
                file_accessed = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getatime(curpath))
                file_modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
                file_created = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(curpath))
                file_size = os.stat(curpath).st_size
                file_convert_size = convert_size(file_size)
                utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                update_id = collection.update_one({'_id': file_db_id}, {
                    "$set": {
                    "file_size": file_convert_size,
                    "file_size_bytes": file_size,
                    "process_datestamp": utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                    "file_created": file_created,
                    "file_accessed": file_accessed,
                    "file_modified": file_modified}},
                    {
                    "$setOnInsert": {
                    "file_path": curpath,
                    "file_name": file,
                    "file_size": file_convert_size,
                    "file_size_bytes": file_size,
                    "process_datestamp": utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                    "file_$reated": file_created,
                    "file_accessed": file_accessed,
                    "file_modified": file_modified}}, upsert=True,
                                                  )
                update_id
                print('ID Updated:', file_db_id)
                print('updating document id:')
        else:
            print('This is not a file:', file)
```

Comment: db.<collection_name>.update( {<filters>}, {<update_value>}, upsert=False) 


pymongo version = pymongo==3.11.0
this is work for me try :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR; The code has two errors: `upsert=True,`. An extra "," and extra "{}"

---

Modify your update operation as:

```
update_id = collection.update_one(
    {'_id': file_db_id},
    {
        "$set": {
                "file_size": file_convert_size,
                "file_size_bytes": file_size,
                "process_datestamp": utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                "file_created": file_created,
                "file_accessed": file_accessed,
                "file_modified": file_modified
        },
        "$setOnInsert": {
                "file_path": curpath,
                "file_name": file,
                "file_size": file_convert_size,
                "file_size_bytes": file_size,
                "process_datestamp": utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                "file_$reated": file_created,
                "file_accessed": file_accessed,
                "file_modified": file_modified
        }
    },
    upsert=True)
```

Your code has two errors: First, you are adding one extra `{}` each for `$set` and `$setOnInsert` See [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#example)

Also, you are doing `upsert=True,`. See this extra `,` this results in a tuple in Python.

Comment: thank you it worked!! Looked myself blind for the last couple of hours

Comment: Glad it helped! An extra "," is a cause of many bugs in the Python code